# XSL sort using multiple fields

Tags: xml, xslt

For reasons that are probably quite simple yet escaping me, I cannot get the following bibliography to sort while copying.

This is a sample of the XML:

```
<listBibl>
  <biblStruct type="book">
    <monogr>
        <title level="book-title">Magic in the Middle Ages</title>
        <author>
            <forename>Richard</forename><surname>Kieckhefer</surname>
        </author>
        <imprint>
            <pubPlace>Toronto</pubPlace>
            <publisher>Cambridge University Press</publisher>
            <date>2000</date>
        </imprint>
    </monogr>
  </biblStruct>
  <biblStruct type="journal-article">
    <analytic>
        <title level="article-title">Social Mentalities and the Cases of Medieval Scepticism</title>
        <author>
            <forename>Susan</forename><surname>Reynolds</surname>
        </author>
    </analytic>
    <monogr>
        <title level="journal-name">Transactions of the Royal Historical Society</title>
        <imprint>
            <biblScope unit="volume">1</biblScope>
            <biblScope unit="page">21-41</biblScope>
            <date>1991</date>
        </imprint>
    </monogr>
  </biblStruct>
  <biblStruct type="book">
    <monogr>
        <title level="book-title">Pathways to Medieval Peasants</title>
        <editor>
            <forename>James Ambrose</forename>
            <surname>Raftis</surname>
        </editor>
        <imprint>
            <pubPlace>Toronto</pubPlace>
            <publisher>Pontifical Institute of Mediaeval Studies</publisher>
            <date>1981</date>
        </imprint>
    </monogr>
  </biblStruct>
  <biblStruct type="book">
    <monogr>
        <title level="book-title">Kingdoms and Communities in Western Europe, 900-1300</title>
        <author>
            <forename>Susan</forename><surname>Reynolds</surname>
        </author>
        <imprint>
            <pubPlace>Oxford</pubPlace>
            <publisher>Oxford University Press</publisher>
            <date>1997</date>
        </imprint>
    </monogr>
  </biblStruct>
<listBibl>
```

Each `biblStruct` represents a work that has either an author(s) or an editor(s), and it is the basis for my sort.

The desired sort logic is this:

first sort 1: find either the first author of a book or an article, depending on `biblStruct @type` and sort on it

```
biblStruct[@type='book']/monogr/author[1]/surname | 
biblStruct[@type='journal-article']/analytic/author[1]/surname
```

then sort 2: get the `title @level` and sort on it

```
title[@level='book-title'] | title[@level='article-title']
```

I'm using a simple `xsl:copy` for now, and even just the basic sort does not work. It just copies the original. XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="listBibl">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="biblStruct[@type='book']/monogr/author[1]/surname | biblStruct[@type='journal-article']/analytic/author[1]/surname "/>
            <xsl:sort select="title[@level='book-title'] | title[@level='article-title'] "/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This should copy the original but sorted by author surname, then title within each author.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which nodes do you want to sort, the `biblStruct` children of each `listBibl`?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear, the `biblStruct` is the object of the sort as each `biblStruct`is effectively a book or an article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `apply-templates` to the children of the `listBibl` then the sort needs to relative to that so if the `biblStruct` is one of the children a path starting with `biblStruct` does not make sense, unless you had such elements nested in each other. And the `title` elements are descendants further down, so the path starting with `title` also seems to miss the target.

If you change the paths to e.g.

```
      <xsl:apply-templates>
          <xsl:sort select=".[@type='book']/monogr/author[1]/surname | .[@type='journal-article']/analytic/author[1]/surname"/>
          <xsl:sort select=".//title[@level='book-title'] | .//title[@level='article-title']"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
```

I hope you get a better result.

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhh/1

Comment: Thanks for this. Looking at your example in http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhh/1 , I notice that the author/surname is not sorting correctly. Surname 'Raftis' is appearing before 'Kieckhefer', even if I add  order="ascending"

Comment: I don't see how your selected sort keys would apply to that item at all, given that it is a `biblStruct[@type = 'book']` but does not have a `monogr/author` at all, only an `editor`. So you will need to explain how you want to treat such elements.

Comment: Ah, right my fault, I didn't see that condition. I've added it and now it works. Thanks again.